# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease' (invalid entry CRC)

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio

There are many other questions for `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'` but I couldn't find any that told what to do for an `invalid entry CRC`.

I'm migrating from Eclipse to Android studio and I am trying to figure out how this works, especially Gradle. I imported an existing Android project. After updating the sdk to api 21 and setting the java 7 path in File/Project Structure, things seemed to be working. I could run my app and get it to build. However, when I do the Gradle assembleRelease or Build/Generate Signed APK I got the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't read [/home/me/adt-bundle/sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar] (invalid entry CRC (expected 0x51d86068 but got 0xe44d416b))
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

I can get it to work if I set `minifyEnabled false` but I want to use proguard, not disable it.

I'm guessing this has something to do with a mismatch between an old filename and a new one, but I can't figure out what it is. I'm about to give up and go back to Eclipse, but I thought I would ask here first. Thanks.

Clues but not solutions (for me):

- [getDefaultProguardFile is unrecognized by Gradle file symbol resolver](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=69731)
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72400
- [Android Studio - ProGuard "java.io.IOException ...bin\classes (No such file or directory)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028171/android-studio-proguard-java-io-ioexception-bin-classes-no-such-file-or-d)
- [What is CRC? And how does it help in error detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957756/what-is-crc-and-how-does-it-help-in-error-detection)

**Update**

It wasn't just imported files from Eclipse that didn't work. Even starting a new project in Android Studio didn't work.

Following @ScottBarta's advice I redownloaded the sdk from [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). (Since I already had Android Studio installed, I just downloaded the "SDK Tools Only" at the bottom of the page.) I renamed the old sdk folder (instead of deleting it). When I opened Android Studio it asked where the sdk folder was so I pointed it to the new one I just downloaded. When gradle tried to do its thing at startup, it found other missing components (the platform, build-tools, appcompat) so I just installed them one by one according to the error messages that gradle gave me.

I am writing this as I download everything. Let's see if it works now...and YES! IT DOES!!! Thank you, @ScottBarta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a corrupted Android SDK -- the bad CRC indicates that some bits in one of the files are wrong. Try reinstalling it.